# Keynote: appear, disappear, reappear in Build Order

Tags: keynote, animation

Is there a way to make an object in the Build order appear, disappear, then reappear on the same slide?

For example, I want to show a blank slide. Then, when I click, I'd like a circle to appear. When I click a second time, I'd like the circle to disappear. Finally, when I click a third time, I'd like the circle to appear again.

Obviously, this is a vastly simplified example of the problem. However, if you can tell me how to accomplish this, I can apply the solution to the very complex slide I'm building.

Also, I know I could do this by duplicating the slide and playing with what is visible on the second slide. However, I would like to accomplish this in a single slide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible to do. ([Provide Kenyote feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/keynote.html) to Apple if you'd like to see this feature added!) Here are two possible alternatives:

- Create 2 copies of the **object** on the slide and have them build in/out in sequence. This will keep your slide deck cleaner and make it easier to align the objects.

  (objects shown separately for illustrative purposes; you'd want to align them perfectly!)

  [image]
- As you suggested, create 2 copies of the **slide** with no transition (so the effect is seamless and there's no delay). This will make it easier to see how you've set up the effect in your list of slides. (But if nothing else on the slide changes, it might just be annoyingly redundant.)

  [image]

Comment: Based on my experiments, this seems like the most reasonable approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add Opacity action set to 0 with duration 0s. Then increase the opacity to 100 with duration 0s. And repeat setting start on click for each action. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the *object*, and have the duplicate version appear on the third click.

[image: image of Keynote Build Inspector]